# windows from application compatibility with window xp,windows7 and windows 8

Tags: .net

I have developed desktop application using .net 3.5 framework on window 7 ,32 bit system .It is working fine on windows 7 ,32 bit and xp, But not working on windows 8.I have build the application with `build properties "platform target" as any`.  How to make the application compatible with windows xp, win7 32 ,64 bit,windows 8 ?

Comment: Have you enabled .NET Framework 3.5 in Control Panel on Win8 machine?

Answer (score 0):

On windows 8, you might need to manually install the .net framework 2.0. Go to Add/Remove programs to do this.

Also, if your application is built against "Any CPU", it must not use any unmanaged libraries, because it will execute as 64 bit on a 64 bit platform. Try setting the target Cpu to x86 to avoid this potential problem.